# How can I correctly handle this POSTed text file?

Tags: ruby, rest, api, multipartform-data

I am having the most difficult time handling a file POSTed in ruby, and am using postman to send the request. The headers of the request are:

```
Content-Type multipart/form-data
```

The body looks like:

```
file crazyfile.txt
```

In my Sinartra server I am doing the following:

```
post '/' do
 request.body.rewind
 contents = request.body.read.to_s
 puts contents
end
```

The output looks like this:

```
---------499771616322077848081915
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="crazyfile.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

holy moly
---------499771616322077848081915
```

How do I get an output of just `holy moly`?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can access the filename with `params[:file][:filename]`, and get access to a [TempFile](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html) via `params[:file][:tempfile]`. The TempFile will allow you to operate on it as if it were, effectively, a File object, so you can access the contents via the `read` method (e.g. `params[:file][:tempfile].read`).

Comment: I just tried this and got it to work with params['file'][:filename] why did I need file with single quotes and filename with colon?

Comment: It could be a difference between versions of Sinatra. The latest documentation showed it using Symbols, but different versions may have used strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your calling `request.body` which is already a string but is the body of the request, not the file attachment itself.  The attachment is passed as a parameter which would get saved as a tempfile when the request is received.

```
post '/' do
 request.body.rewind
 file_attachment_contents = request.params[:file][:tempfile].read
 puts file_attachment_contents
end
```